# How to grant permission to AAD native app in PowerShell 6?

Tags: azure-active-directory, powershell-core, nativeapplication, powershell-v6.0

I registered a native application on Azure Active Directory via powershell 6 (module AzureAD.Standard.Preview) and I need to grant the permissions with powershell 6 code (Settings > Required permissions> Grant permissions). I'm using the AZ modules.

I tried with this solution http://www.lieben.nu/liebensraum/2018/04/how-to-grant-oauth2-permissions-to-an-azure-ad-application-using-powershell-unattended-silently but this use powershell 5 and the old AzureRM module. It doesn't work with AZ module because the refresh token doesn't exist.

How is it possible to grant permission to a native app registered on AAD with PowerShell 6 and the AZ module?

Comment: You could refer to this [PowerShell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Manage-AzureAppRegistration-0f3256c6) to grant permission. For the details, please read [here](https://realtimeuc.com/2017/12/manage-azureappregistration/).

Comment: @SunnySun I guess there is no workable  power shell command for application permission at this stage. Its better to use Azure CLI for that.

Comment: Checking with the chrome inspector and clicking on the Grant Permission I can see a POST request to the following endpoint https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/RegisteredApplications/9625c033-b29e-4430-9fe9-b5cc5fd93773/Consent?onBehalfOfAll=false and the header contains a Bearer Authorization Token.
Maybe there is no PowerShell command to grant the permissions but I can reproduce the post request. I tried to reproduce this post request but I don't know how to get this token with PowerShell 6 and AZ module. How can I do?